# Exchange 2016 cant access OWA - incorrect user ID and password

Tags: exchange, outlook-web-app, activesync

Originally i was having issue to use public network to access my exchange 2016 OWA,

After my network team allowed the NAT 443 port, i'm able to land on OWA web pages externally, but no matter what credential i type in, it wont allow me to login into OWA, it state incorrect user account and password!

in my exchange server, i cant login ecp or owa as well..
Checked in event log, there lot of MSEXchange ADAccess error event ID 2937 and 4127.

Urgently need feedback on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi,

1. When you tried to login the Outlook, is the same issue occurred in the scenario?
2. Do other services like ActiveSync, PowerShell etc. have the issue?
3. Do you find other errors in the Exchange Management Shell (EMS) when you use it?

Try to restart IIS Manager, if the issue is still alive (if issue still persists), please check the following configurations:

1. Could you please provide the errors which displayed when you access ECP, OWA and EMS in the Exchange Server?
2. Please use two cmdlets to check the configurations of OWA or ECP Virtual Directory:

   Get-OwaVirtualDirectory | fl  & Get-EcpVirtualDirectory | fl

   If you can’t connect to EMS, please use remote PowerShell
   (Run the following command in the Windows PowerShell):

   1)  $UserCredential = Get-Credential

   2) $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http:///PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $UserCredential

   3) Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking

   4) If you want to disconnect the remote PowerShell session: Remove-PSSession $Session

   More details about Remote PowerShell: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-server/connect-to-exchange-servers-using-remote-powershell?view=exchange-ps
3. To get further progress, you can check and provide the information about OWA, ECP or other services’ Authentication, HTTP Redirect, SSL Settings and Logging (the log path is %SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles by default) in the IIS.
   [image]

You can open the IIS Logging of the latest time after you found this issue by Excel form, and filter the mailbox name which has the issue.

Then check whether the log has the HTTP status codes. If so, please view the document about these codes: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0

> > in my exchange server, i cant login ecp or owa as well.. Checked in event log, there lot of MSEXchange ADAccess error event ID 2937 and 4127.

I searched some documents about Event ID 2937 and 4127 for you: ID2937 & ID 4127.  Check whether your issues are same as them, but I advise that you can use the keyword(OWA) of filter in Event Viewer to view whether it has errors about OWA.

Best regards,

Ivan Wang